# Class number of positive definite binary quadratic forms formula

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, legendre-symbol

I've been doing some computational research into the class number $h(d)$ which for my purposes is defined as the number of positive definite binary quadratic forms $(a,b,c)$ which are reduced, primative, and have discriminant $d = b^2 - 4ac$.

After checking for afew values of $p$ and $d$ it seems the following holds:
$$h(dp^2) = \left[ p - \left(\frac dp\right)\right] h(d) \tag{$*$} $$
where $d<-4$, $p$ is an odd prime, and $(d/p)$ is the Legendre Symbol.

I am looking for a source to cite ($*$) or a more general result from but have failed to find one - could anyone provide such a source?

[I'm not really looking for a proof of $(*)$ unless it is especially accessible as my knowledge of the group theory underlying quadratic forms is limited]

Comment: not quite. The correct results are section 7.1 in Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. (pages 109-119) Probably in Buchmann and Vollmer as well.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks very much for this its very helpful. I'm trying to understand where the true result (on page 117-119) differs from my own but I can't find the method used enumerate the solutions $(x_i, y_i)$ to $x^2 - dy^2  = 4$?

Comment: when $\Delta < -4$ you get $s=1,$ so that agrees with your conjecture. Next, $$ h(-3p^2) = \frac{p-(-3|p)}{3} $$ when $p > 3.$ $$ h(-4p^2) = \frac{p-(-1|p)}{2} $$ The bit about $x^2 - \Delta y^2 = 4$ applies most directly with positive discriminants. Similarly in Theorem 7.5, take $Y_1$ even when $\Delta < 4$